# archlinux root can't edit /etc/pacman.conf

Tags: linux, archlinux

I have a fresh install of arch linux, and i'm trying to edit my pacman config file, and I get this when trying to edit it:

```
[yochran@archboot ~]$ su root
Password: 
[root@archboot yochran]# EDITOR=nano /etc/pacman.conf
bash: /etc/pacman.conf: Permission denied
[root@archboot yochran]#
```

I've also tried vim, and editing the file manually. I do not have permission to do any, not through sudo (even though I have wheel and wheen has ALL).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing there is run the command `/etc/pacman.conf` (which doesn't look right to me. Is it executable?) having setup environment variable `EDITOR` to `nano`. It looks like what you really want to do is:

```
nano /etc/pacman.conf
```

Or a (different) command is used to edit that file (which could use the environment variable).

Comment: This is correct. `EDITOR` is an environment variable that tells the system which editor is your choice for various editing commands (like `crontab -e`, etc.).

Comment: Ok.... but then `/etc/pacman.conf` is an executable? Because then it sounds like a different thing should be called to edit the file (like when we call `crontab -e`, we don't use `EDITOR=nano /etc/crontab`).

Comment: What? That kind of isn't at all what I said. You ***Certainly*** can use `EDITOR=something` before any command like `crontab -e`. ..`crontab -e` is a command, `/etc/crontab` is a path to a file. Setting variables (environment variables that the command is looking for) before calling a command is relatively common - but I am not sure the point you're attempting to make?

Comment: You can use `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` because that is perfectly valid. `EDITOR=nano /etc/crontab` will give you the exact same `Permission denied` error that op is asking about.

Comment: Don't know if you already realized my point (I do understand yours.... I am very aware that we can set environment variables when calling a command).

Comment: Just in case, here's the gist of it: `/etc/pacman.conf` is not an executable.

Comment: Yep - no I understand your point. I was just trying to help, but I guess you got this :)

Comment: @BryanHeden I don't understand? `EDITOR=foo` does NOT invoke `foo` as the editor for whatever follows. It simply sets the `EDITOR` environment variable so that any application that uses the command `$EDITOR somefile` will invoke that editor through the use of the variable. Setting the variable on the command line, e.g.  `EDITOR=nano /etc/pacman/conf` won't invoke nano opening `/etc/pacman.conf`, but after setting `EDITOR=nano`, `$EDITOR /etc/pacman.conf` will.

Comment: ... update, it appears they have another command `sensible-editor`, which does honor the environment variable.  I'm not sure if this will work on Arch tho.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```bash
EDITOR=nano /etc/pacman.conf
```

... should be:

```bash
EDITOR=nano sensible-editor /etc/pacman.conf
# ----------^
```

Note, this may not work on all platforms.

Comment: You're mixing up `editor` with `sensible-editor`. You can run `EDITOR=nano sensible-editor /etc/pacman.conf`, but that's just a convoluted way of running `nano /etc/pacman.conf` (ignoring `VISUAL`). `EDITOR=nano $EDITOR …` won't do what you seem to think it does: it expands `$EDITOR` before doing the assignment, so it uses whatever value `EDITOR has before the command, and in particular tries to run `/etc/pacman.conf` as a command if `EDITOR` isn't set.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks!  That fixes it, updated. :). Good catch on the order of operations, I've removed that solution since it doesn't work.